# SKNode failing to find childNodeWithName:

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I am searching for an `SKNode` in an `SKScene` by using the `childNodeWithName:` method. To set the name I am using an `NSManagedObjectID`'s URI string representation, obtained like so:

`[[managedObjectID URIRepresentation] absoluteString];`

This gives a node name of:

> x-coredata://0856426F-EA66-4D28-A88A-FF49225F69B6/Object/p4

However, the `childNodeWithName:` method returns nil. The node is clearly present when inspecting in the debugger, along with two other nodes:

```
<__NSArrayI 0x9933eb0>(

<SKSpriteNode> name:'(null)' texture:['nil'] position:{160, 284} size:{320, 568} rotation:0.00,

<SKSpriteNode> name:'x-coredata://0856426F-EA66-4D28-A88A-FF49225F69B6/Object/p4' texture:['nil'] position:{31, 537} size:{50, 50} rotation:0.00,

<SKSpriteNode> name:'x-coredata://0856426F-EA66-4D28-A88A-FF49225F69B6/Object/p1' texture:['nil'] position:{217, 416} size:{50, 50} rotation:0.00

)
```

And to reinforce this, if I set the node name to something like "testingName", then the node is returned as expected.

This leads me to believe that Sprite Kit doesn't like something about the name I have used. Is anyone aware of naming restrictions, or perhaps has an idea as to why a URL format would give a problem here?

Thanks.

Comment: childnodewithname uses a simplified regex-like search, for example "//name*" - I bet the problem is due to the slashes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer [here](https://twitter.com/kylefuller/status/452238602916089857) by [@kylefuller](https://twitter.com/kylefuller).

From Apple:

> The search uses common regular expression semantics.
>
> "//" - When placed at the start of the search string, this specifies that the search should begin at the root node and be performed recursively across the entire node tree. It is not legal anywhere else in the search string.

Answer (score 2):

I thought I would add something regarding this issue as I wasted a few hours on this.

My project has a Sprite kit scene graph as follows:

`SKScene-> SKNode(myWorld)->SKNode(camera)` as per Apple's example. However when using

```
var cameraNode = self.childNodeWithName("camera")
```

the node being returned was always nil. Apple documentation didn't mention the '//' stated by [Andy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22874625/sknode-failing-to-find-childnodewithname/22875336#22875336). It seems that the function `childNodeWithName` will only search the children of the node specified (in this case the scene). As soon as I found this post I changed the line to

```
var cameraNode = self.childNodeWithName("//camera")
```

it can now find the `camera` node regardless of it's level in the scenegraph.